# Chef Data_bag usage via Ruby Recipe error?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, databags

I have a Chef DataBag that I'm trying to read and use inside of a chef recipe, and its kicking my ass. Please note: I'm not a programmer, and the use of Chef is my first entry into Ruby.

Based off of the examples I've found online, here is the contents of the databag "AWSProd" that lives in a folder called WEB under the data_bags folder on my Chef server:

```
{
  "id" : "AWSProd",
  "hosted_sites" : {
    "siteA" : [
      {
        "site_name" : "siteA",
        "site_doc_root_folder" : "siteA",
        "site_simlink" : ""
     }
     ],
     "siteB" : [
      {
        "site_name" : "siteB",
        "site_doc_root_folder" : "siteB",
        "site_simlink" : ""
      }
      ]
  }
}
```

In my recipe, I'm using the following to grab the Databag for use:

```
WEB = data_bag("WEB")
WEB_env_globals = data_bag_item("WEB", node.chef_environment)
```

Then I basically want to iterate each site (siteA, siteB, etc) and grab those individual values for site_name, site_doc_root_folder, etc...

I'm trying to just echo the values so I know they work. I tried this:

```
WEB_env_globals["hosted_sites"].each do |site|
  each_sitename = site["site_name"] ## can't convert String into Integer
  each_site_doc_root_folder = site["site_doc_root_folder"]
  each_site_simlink = site["site_simlink"]

  execute "echo each site" do
    command "echo #{each_sitename} #{each_site_doc_root_folder} #{each_site_simlink}"
    action :run
  end

end
```

But I received a "can't convert String into Integer" error on the line where I have the double ##.

Then I tried replacing that line with something like this:

```
each_sitename = WEB_env_globals["hosted_sites"][site]["site_name"]
```

But then I get an "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" error on that line.

I know I'm missing something completely basic with Ruby here, and I've been looking for about an hour for a clear explanation and cant find one. Help me Ruby-Won-Kenobi...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I got it! Took a little education on Hash Vs Arrays...

Below is the correct ruby block:

```
WEB_env_globals["hosted_sites"].each do |site,data|

  data.each do |hash|
    each_sitename = hash["site_name"]
    each_site_doc_root_folder = hash["site_doc_root_folder"]
    each_site_simlink = hash["site_simlink"]

      execute "echo each site #{site}" do
        command "echo #{each_sitename} #{each_site_doc_root_folder} #{each_site_simlink}"
        action :run
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Yea, that works, but I'd suggest you change the structure of your databag.  You're listing the sitename twice, for example, which is not really needed.

Comment: Thanks Tejay, we have a few sites that have sitenames that are ridiculous, so we wanted a "plain english" tag for the site. Although I guess that could just be another value in the list... Good food for thought!

Comment: if that case, I would suggest you go with the approach that coderanger pointed out.  That allows you to use an ID and name while still keeping a cleaner (and more ruby like) data structure.

Answer (score 1):

In your data bag item, each site is an array of hashes. I don't think this is what you intended, since you would need to access it like:

```
site[0]["site_name"]
```

What you probably wanted was a data bag item like:

```
{
  "id" : "AWSProd",
  "hosted_sites" : {
    "siteA" : {
        "site_name" : "siteA",
        "site_doc_root_folder" : "siteA",
        "site_simlink" : ""
     },
     "siteB" : {
        "site_name" : "siteB",
        "site_doc_root_folder" : "siteB",
        "site_simlink" : ""
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `.each` method on a `Hash`, but only capturing the key.
`WEB_env_globals['hosted_sites'].each do |key, value|` - but you only gave it a name for the key.

`each_sitename = site[....]` - remember that site is the key (a String), so you're calling the `[]` method on `String` which expects an Integer and returns the char at that index.

**You can call `.class` on any ruby object to find out what type it is.  This is very helpful for troublshooting*

So you can change your databag to use an array of hashes:

change your databag:

```
{
  "id" : "AWSProd",
  "hosted_sites" : [
    {
      "site_name" : "siteA",
      "site_doc_root_folder" : "siteA",
      "site_simlink" : ""
    },
    {
      "site_name" : "siteB",
      "site_doc_root_folder" : "siteB",
      "site_simlink" : ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Or leave it alone and try this for your code: (note I also don't use an `execute` block for my debugging)

```
WEB_env_globals["hosted_sites"].each do |sitename, site_array|
  site_array.each do |site|
    each_sitename = site["site_name"]
    each_site_doc_root_folder = site["site_doc_root_folder"]
    each_site_simlink = site["site_simlink"]

     Chef::Log.debug "#{each_sitename} #{each_site_doc_root_folder} #{each_site_simlink}"
     # you could use puts or a higher level log message to make this easier to see in your output.
  end
```

end